# TFS 2017/GIT - pull request having conflicts, how to edit/resolve them w/out VS2017 team explorer?

Tags: git, tfs, request, visual-studio-2017, pull

I am using TFS (V# 16.131.28106.2) and git along with it.  TFS gives web interface and it is used to create pull requests.
I also use VS2017 and its Team Explorer.  Team Explorer (same project, set to work with tfs/git repository) is used for most operations - stage, commit, pull, sync, push, etc...
One specific problem I encountered is when pull request (created in TFS web interface) has conflicts it renders a message: "Next steps: Manually resolve these conflicts and push new changes to the source branch.".
The problem?  I can't resolve conflicting files (typically having '<<<...', '===...', and '>>>...' markers) in VS2017 team explorer! Nor I can resolve them through TFS web interface!?
What is the best workflow to resolve the conflicts (through a 3rd tool supposedly) prior to pull request approval?
thanks

Comment: Manually checkout origin branch, merge target branch into origin branch, resolve conflicts, commit and push changes.

Comment: @Alex, thank you for the reply.
If I did that, I would invalidate the Pull Request that is in TFS/GIT.  Based on policy, the code merger has to go through pull request/merger (into master branch).
Again, the question is very specific (within TFS/GIT environment).  It is about pull request operation not being able to complete due to conflicting files.  The goad is to be able to do two things: 1. resolve the underlying conflicts in the background (TFS/GI); 2.based on no conflicts, approve the pull request in TFS/GIT.

Comment: Refer to the documentation on resolving merge conflicts using Visual Studio. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/merging?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @DanielMann, the conflict is in "TFS/GIT Pull Request".  If I do a merge based on VS team explorer, the same conflict comes in it too.  I can resolve it in VS through a merge.  But if I do that and commit/push the change(s), my TFS/GIT Pull Request is invalidated: "There are no changes to merge between the selected branches."

Comment: If you merged master into your PR branch, then you should be able to edit the conflicts in Visual Studio.  Can you provide a description of your workflow (how you got into a state where you have the files locally with the conflict markers) and some screenshots?

Comment: You won't see your conflicts in your local if you don't merge the target branch of the PR into your local to get it.  Once you merge like Alex recommended, resolve conflicts, commit, push, the PR should automatically update to include the latest version from the branch.  Depending on the version, TFS will also give you a pretty nice interface to review the changes in different updates to the PR.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, branch,"ERRLOG"-->master.  Change 20 files, C#,etc. whatsnew.txt, conflicts Team member has to submit a "PR" using TFS web UI.  WN.txt gave conflict in the TFS UI: "Next steps: Manually resolve these conflicts and push new changes to the source branch." DEVs must submit PR thru TFS/GIT to let designated prs/grp do code review. TFS/GIT webUI doesn't allow editing conflicts. VS17 isnt useful, because if VS17 is used, the DEV will resolve conflicts via merge and commit/push the merge (Feature/ERROR_LOG-->master), thus invalidating TFS/GIT PR itself.

Comment: @ArtMelk You fix the merge conflict by merging the **target** branch into your **source** branch and resolving the conflicts there, then push the merge, which will automatically update your pull request.

Answer (score 1):

While I think you might have some kind of process or policy issue that is making this a problem for you, I believe if you were to install the marketplace extension [Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab), you would be able to handle the merge conflict in the web interface.

Comment: it appears this is exactly the tool that would do the job for us.  Even though I have not installed it yet (we put a request to OPs to do that).  Thanks